# IOS Shared Application hide StatusBar

Tags: iphone, uiapplication, uistatusbar

I am hiding the Status bar with the below code and it gives me a memory warning level1 . It does nothing to the app itself during the memory warning but I do not like to have such things happening. Is there somthing I am doing wrong? or and con someone confirm a IOS bug? Not a huge deal just bothering me , so any info is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES   
withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

Comment: Does it give you the warning if you don't hide it?

Comment: Could you post the warning too?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
    { 
        if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:)]) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO]; 
            } 
            else { 
                id<UIApplicationDeprecatedMethods> app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
                [app setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
            }
}
```

and declare in your .h

```
@protocol UIApplicationDeprecatedMethods
- (void)setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated;
@end
```

Hope it helps..